# Fading in a previously hidden iframe in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, iframe

CSS

```
iframe {
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
    $('iframe').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="ifrm">external link</a>

<iframe name="ifrm"></iframe>
```

The above works in IE and Chrome, but when I try it out in Firefox, the iframe never displays. Any workarounds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in a div and fade that in.

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="ifrm">external link</a>
<div id="iframeContainer" style="display:none;">
    <iframe name="ifrm"></iframe>
</div>

$(function() {
    $('iframe').load(function() {
        $('#iframeContainer').fadeIn('fast');
    });
})
```

Comment: Thx, I went a different route, but I am sure your solution would work.